react-native-video player issue
useFocusEffect(
   
    React.useCallback(() => {
      // Start playing the video when the screen gains focus
      if (videoRef.current) {
        setPlaybackRate(1.0);
        
      }
      // Pause the video when the screen loses focus
      return () => {
      

        if (videoRef.current) {
          setPlaybackRate(0);
          console.log("videoRef!! ",elapsedTime)

        // Set isVisible to false when tab chang
        }else{
        
          console.log("Player Destroyed !! ",elapsedTime)
          console.log("Player Destroyed !! ",videoId,videoName)
             fetchWatchHistory(phoneNumber,videoId,videoName,elapsedTime,1);

         }
      };
    }, [videoRef,elapsedTime])
  );

this is my function to call when i loss my screen focus it pause my video but i works on those iphone device whose ios version is greater then 16
but this  function is not working on those iphone devices whose ios version is less then 16
when i navigate or loss screen focus my video still play not paused
give solution of this problem
i want to pause my video in those i phone device whose ios version is less than 16

What version of react-native-video are you using? And is there a reason you arent just calling videoRef's pause/play function? The current docs says that setting the rate to 0 only pauses on iOS https://thewidlarzgroup.github.io/react-native-video/component/props#rate

I digged a little further and the video component has a paused prop. If you want to avoid using the video component's ref to pause, then you could create a variable isFocused that is updated in the useFocusEffect hook, and then do <Video paused={!isFocused} rate={playbackRate}/>

use react-native-video version  6.5.0
